# Spark sql: query with case and thousands of columns

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera-cdh

I had a table with **two thousands columns**. i need to modify few columns data based on flag column.

```
tableSchemaRDD.registerAsTable("customer")
var results = sqlContext.sql("select *,case when flag1 = 'A' then null else charges end as charges, flag2 = 'B' then null then else stax end as stax from customer")
```

flag1,flag2, charges,stax are the columns from my table. the above code will give extra two coumns along with original columns. How can i get all columns with modified columns (charges,stax) based on flag columns.

Comment: Something has gone very, very wrong.

Comment: can you post what is the table structure and what is the output that you expecting?

Comment: which spark version you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use asterisk ( * ), actually asterisk tells you have to bring all columns, after that you are using the two cases which are responsible for two new columns. You just have to remove asterisk ( * ) and place the column names comma separated without those column names which you are going to modify. In this way those two old columns will not be shown.
If you are using Spark 1.3 then its very easy for DataFrame, like

```
val columsNames = df.schema.fieldNames
  .filter(fieldName => {
    !fieldName.equals("charges") && !fieldName.equals("stax")
  }).mkString(",")
```

Don't exactly remember that there are methods/properties in SchemaRDD or not.

**EDITED:**
Just understand the issue, asterisk tells bring all old columns, then you are using two new cases (two new columns.) also, where in your scenario you have to specify columns with their names without charges and stax, as these are your new columns, those will be populated by cases.

Suppose you have a table customer which has 4 columns, id name charges stax and you write the query like you are writing

> select *,case when flag1 = 'A' then null else charges end as charges, flag2 = 'B' then null then else stax end as stax from customer

This will give you 6 columns, 4 for asterisk ( * ) as there are four columns in the table. and 2 for your cases. Instead of asterisk ( * ), you have to query like

```
select id , name ,case when flag1 = 'A' then null else charges end as charges, flag2 = 'B' then null then else stax end as stax from customer
```

This will result in 4 columns, id, name as they are (OLD). Stax and Charges (new) result of your cases.

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: I am using spark 1.2.

Comment: no problem, if you know schema i.e. column names then just use those comma separated instead of asterisk. see my edited post.

Comment: also you can do same stuff with schemaRDD also, I've checked it,